# Knockoutjs View Management

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have experience with Backbone + React and Angularjs and I'm trying to correlate concepts between knockoutjs and the aforementioned libraries/frameworks.

While I believe I understand most aspects of knockoutjs, I would appreciate help in clarifying the following:

1. In Backbone usually the main or parent view is mounted/unmounted by the router and all subsequent state changes are handled by the view in concert with the model. How is one supposed to add/remove views from the DOM in Knockout? I assume state changes are handled by the view and the view-model respectively.
2. Which routing library/framework (i.e. sammyjs, backbonejs, etc) works well with Knockout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Angualar is a framework. Knockout is only a library. (sorry, not sure about Backbone and React)

It would be a fairer comparison to compare Angular to Durandal.

Durandal much like Angular is a framework. The reason i mention Durandal is that for the model binding it is using Knockout.
It also composes the views and has routing capability out of the box.
http://durandaljs.com/

In answer to your initial questions..

1) Knockout doesn't directly deal with the concept of serving a view, it simply allows you to bind a view against a view model. I'm not saying it cant do this, just that you would have to implement it yourself.

2) As knockout is a library it can be easily plugged in and used along side other libraries that you already know like sammyjs.